# Extracting range from of an array

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

From the following single cell array:

```
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34
```

I'd like to extract `3,5,8,13,21` into a single cell by specifying index 4 : index 8 of the split of that cell.

**The Challenge** is that I'll need it be in a single step (cannot split array into different cells, as these arrays will get very long and will otherwise produce far too many cells for google sheets to handle.

I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

To get the desired result from your example in just one formula please try the following:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(", ",TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(A1,",",true)),"select * offset "&8-4&" "))),"(, \d+$)","")
```

*(assuming `A1` holds your numbers)*

*I hope this is what you are looking for. If not let us know.*

Answer (score 0):

Update :

Here's a way to do it with `=query()`

```
=join(",",
    QUERY(
        SPLIT(A1,",",true),
        "SELECT "&JOIN(",",ARRAYFORMULA("Col"&ROW(indirect("A"&A6+1&":A"&A7+1))))
    )
)
```

With :

- `A1` as the initial cell
- `A6` is parameter 1
- `A7` is parameter 2

The demo sheet has been updated.

---

Using a single step :

First `split()` to create an array

```
=SPLIT(A1,",",true)
```

Then `Offset` + `array_constrain` to pick what you need.

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(OFFSET(A2:J2,0,A6),1,count(A2:J2)-(A7-A6)-1)
```

Finally using join() :

```
=JOIN(",",
ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(OFFSET(A2:J2,0,A6),1,count(A2:J2)-(A7-A6)-1)
)
```

[Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1d6Bny76X3BuJeUYjvysq4oP1dbXJFAXhhkG_ZygjjU0/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Ah thanks pjmg! Though, is there any way to do this in a single step without splitting the cell up into a multi-cell array?

Comment: I'm not sure, I tried with `index()` (spoiler : doesn't do the job). There's maybe a way with `=query()` but it can be very hard to scale this way if you need to re-use the formula IMO multiple times or on another sheet. I'll edit my answer later if I find a way.

Comment: @devans I updated my answer and the demo sheet. Don't forget to accept the answer if it correspond to what you're looking for